# Raid Information Through ESXi

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi

I have created a few virtual disks using Raid controller from a Dell server. And then I installed ESXi on the server. But when I view the virtualdisk on the esxi under storage, I see all of them, but I cant tell which one is which.

e.g I have a few raid 1 disks and a few raid 0 disks, but can't identify and distinguish among them under ESXi.

any inputs?

Comment: Are they of different sizes?

Comment: Nope. Theyre all the same size. Just the difference is some are mirrored others arent.

Comment: I'm sure there's a "real" solution, though I don't know it off-hand. Have you considered simply configuring the virtual disks one at a time and configuring them, as opposed to configuring all at once and being left with the extra guesswork?

Comment: Nope, I actually configured them all together not knowing won't be able to find out which one is which under ESXi

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to determine which logical/virtual drives are which.

The VMware client will display your block devices and how they're enumerated. You should know the capacities of your virtual drives. This should be enough to go on.

[image]

In addition, if you have your Dell OMSA agents or PERC/MegaRAID .vibs installed (or a custom Dell ISO), the virtual disk information should also be displayed under the hardware tab.

[image]

Either way, these things usually show up in order...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However all the Virtual Disks in my server are of same size, the only difference being some are Mirrored.

Comment: You ignored my suggestion about the hardware-specific drivers. The ESXi Hardware take can tell you which disks are which, provided you have the drivers loaded for your controller/platform.

Comment: Under my hardware, I see under storage adapters DELL PERC H710P vmbha0  SCSI. Under details i see virtual disks but no raid information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Each disk should have a unique identifier that you can see by selecting the Host and then going to Configuration > Storage. Click on the Devices View for easiest sorting. Compare that to what you have created. It should show you somewhere in the RAID interface that info.

In the odd chance you can't determine it that way. Try taking one or more of the LUNs offline to see which is which.

That said, make sure that you are not creating too many separate disks. You said this was a single server. I should be a pretty big server to have that many separate disks that are RAID 0 and 1. Otherwise they're likely sharing the same Physical Drives and you might be better served changing that up.

On a side note:
Just yesterday I created a few Datastores for a new SQL server and had planned on making 2 of them 1TB each. I didn't feel matching the IQNs so I just made one 900GB for now.

Hope that all helps.